# Eclipse: Most useful refactorings

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

Every now and again, I make use of the Eclipse refactoring feature. Some techniques are more obvious then others and some I never tried.

What refactoring is most useful for you and why?

Note: I find this presentation very useful, perhaps because it is example driven therefore easy to understand:

"[Refactoring for everyone - How and why to use Eclipse's automated refactoring features](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecref/)"

Edit: This article is useful as well (Thanks jitter)

[Explore refactoring functions in Eclipse JDT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-refactoring/index.html)

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-refactoring/index.html

Comment: The reference for refactoring is Martin Fowlers book "Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code". Eclipse implements a lot of these - as other IDE (netbeans, IntelliJ) - to me it's on of THE strengths of an IDE and a reason to not start programming Java without one.

Comment: Subjective, doesn't have a single answer, topic should be marked CW.

Comment: There's no right answer to this, I suggest to put it as a Community wiki

Comment: I would rephrase the question - is there any plugin for Eclipse better or as good as Eclipse's "native" refactoring?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It is an interesting question. I know what works for me and it is interesting to see what others use.

I decided to take a more scientific approach to determine the most commonly used refactoring commands. Eclipse has a [Usage Data Collector (UDC)](http://www.eclipse.org/org/usagedata/index.php) feature built in. The data is [publicly available](http://www.eclipse.org/org/usagedata/results.php?kind=command&sort=element). I took the data and extracted the following graph which shows the most commonly used editing commands (without navigation commands).

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091207-bmcng36rjy837sqmcx58b85age.gif](http://img.skitch.com/20091207-bmcng36rjy837sqmcx58b85age.gif)

However, I am a strong believer in "Save Actions" for formatting and organizing imports (read [my article about it](http://blog.zvikico.com/problog/2007/08/eclipse-europa-.html)), so I wouldn't count those. I would also remove the commenting actions. The picture looks like this: [alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091207-ieas1mk5114fwitucqkqxyw6t.gif](http://img.skitch.com/20091207-ieas1mk5114fwitucqkqxyw6t.gif)

Comment: +1 Cool work. Very insightful...

Comment: Awesome! Empirical research ftw!

Comment: Indeed, very cool data! But, this relies on the habits of any monkey that programs on eclipse. We need a separate DB for *real* coders to study from.

Comment: Images are broken.

Answer (score 30):

**Rename** - because giving things meaningful names is the best way to write self-documenting code. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

**Extract method** - whenever a method gets too long. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

**Extract constant** - because magic numbers are bad. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (refactoring menu, there's no direct shortcut).

**Inline/introduce variable** - to remove clutter from methods. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (inline), <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (introduce)

Answer (score 20):

My favourites (in order of using):

1. Rename (`Alt-Shift-R`, or `Ctrl-1` for faster in-file renaming)
   Good renaming variables,methods,etc. without side effects.
2. Extract Variable (`Ctrl-1`, `Alt-Shift-L`)
   Good for splitting a quick-made-100-character-line to separate steps.
3. Extract Method (`Alt-Shift-M`)
   Create a method out of some code without any side effects.
4. Split Variable Declaration (`Ctrl-1`)
   Good when you initialize a variable at the declaration and now find out, that the initialisation needs to be in a try- or if-block.
5. Change Method Signature (`Alt-Shift-C`)
   The handy Swiss Army Knife of method signature manipulation, including default values for new parameters.
6. Pull Up/Push Down
   Pull methods and variables to a generic interface or superclass or push it down to a subclass
7. Extract Interface/Superclass
   Extract an interface or a superclass out of the current class. Very handy.

Comment: +1 for a few refactorings I don't know but like.

Comment: Ctrl 1 does not work for me.

Comment: for splitting the variable declaration, could you please mention that for moving the declaration outside of a containing code block (e.g. outside of a try-catch block) one can use the Alt+Up-Arrow combination? I was looking for this, did not find it here, but found elsewhere I thought would be good if you included that in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

My favorites:

1. Renaming
2. Pull up/Push Down
3. Extract Method

Answer (score 5):

The most popular refactorings have been stated, and I entirely agree with them.

**Code formatter** (*Source*, *Format* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>) is one of the features of the IDE I use very often. True, it is not refactoring, but it improves code readability while maintaining your coding style: simply head to *Preferences*, *Java*, *Code Style*, *Formatter* and tell Eclipse how you want your code to look!

**Generate Getters and Setters** is also a feature I find to save time when writing Java beans.

Comment: I definitively use most CTRL+SHIFT+7 (or /) for (un)commenting lines.

Comment: FYI - (and maybe you know or can't use it for whatever reason)...you can setup 'Save Actions' to auto-format for you (amongst other things). I find this helpful insofar as not having to manually format via ctrl+shift+f

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse has perhaps the least refactorings for all the popular IDEs. You might consider Netbeans or IntelliJ (Community edition is free). Conversely Eclipse has possibly the best debugger. ;)

I use refactoring as I write the code (which I have found speeds up writing by about 15%) so IntelliJ's ability to refactor code which does not compile very useful for me.  The other IDEs may support this now (does any one know?)
I find IntelliJ's smart complete is a fair bit smarter as well.

I have tested retyping a files from printout (originally written in eclipse) and found I used 30% less keys and 50% less mouse movements when typing the file with IntelliJ (compared with Eclipse) I would estimate Netbeans to be somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

My favorites are:

1) Rename - It works on method names, variable names, class names, fields-- really anything with a name.
2) Convert Anonymous Class to Nested - Helps with debugging, lets you reuse logic (such as a comparator) that you only thought that you'd use in one place. 
3) Convert Member Type to Top Level - Frequently after making an anonymous class into a nested class I discover that the class is useful elsewhere. This refactoring is perfect then.

Answer (score 1):

What I use the most is Rename, Extract Method and Change Method Signature, in that order.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL + 1 on a red lined section, i.e. quick fix.

Comment: I don't think "quick fix" can be classed as a refactoring

Comment: I agree with adrian - a quick fix will change the behaviour of the code and isn't a refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

I like the Extract Method (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>), and since [**3.6M1**](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M1-200908061400/eclipse-news-M1.html#JDT), it now handles selections that contain continue statements.

> To preserve the semantics of the existing code, the selection needs to include the last statement of the loop. In the extracted method, continue statements are changed to return:

[Extract method refactoring with continue http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M1-200908061400/images/extract-method-continue.png](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M1-200908061400/images/extract-method-continue.png)

> For a selection that would need multiple return values in the extracted method, Eclipse now lists the conflicting variables in the error message:

[Extract method refactoring with an ambiguous return value error http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M1-200908061400/images/extract-method-multiple-return-values.png](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M1-200908061400/images/extract-method-multiple-return-values.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use :

1- Rename  - to correct better method name

2- Move  - to organize my package in better ways, like when I start my project, it was so small so no need of a io package, but now yes.

3- Generate Comments -when I create a .class  avoid me to re-copy the GPL license, etc

4- Correct Indentation - to keep my code readable.

Comment: `Correct Indentation`  :  `CNTRL` + `SHIFT` + `F`

Comment: I use Ctrl + I  for Correct Indentation

Comment: Control-shift-F is not indentation, it is formatting, which *also* performs indentation. A step higher is Clean-up, which is amazingly brilliant at times (especially if you like e.g. `final` like me) and also performs formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth reading this research: [How do API evolve? A story of refactoring.](http://netfiles.uiuc.edu/dig/papers/JSME_API_Evolution.pdf) by D. Dig and R. Johnson.

The authors noticed that 80% of the changes were refactorings and classified them.  Here is the abstract:

> Frameworks and libraries change their
>   APIs. Migrating an application to the
>   new API is tedious and disrupts the
>   development process. Although some
>   tools and ideas have been proposed to
>   solve the evolution of APIs, most
>   updates are done manually. To better
>   understand the requirements for
>   migration tools, we studied the API
>   changes of four frameworks and one
>   library. We discovered that the
>   changes that break existing
>   applications are not random, but tend
>   to fall into particular categories.
>   Over 80% of these changes are
>   refactorings. This suggests that
>   refactoring-based migration tools
>   should be used to update applications.

Answer (score -3):

"It's also worth reading this research: How do API evolve? A story of refactoring. by D. Dig and R. Johnson.

The authors noticed that 80% of the changes were refactorings and classified them. Here is the abstract ... "

80% of the BREAKING changes were observed to be refactorings.
The refactorings themselves formed only 20 - 30% of the API changes..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and sounds like anecdotal evidence against refactoring.